# "Already has a reference to Essential.Diagnostics"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, package-managers

I tried installing Essential.Diagnostics via

```
Install-Package Essential.Diagnostics
```

But I had an issue where it said I was referencing something that didn't exist, so I tried removing the reference, and now I don't know how to re-add it. When I run the above command in the Package Manager Console again, it keeps saying my project already has a reference to it, even though I can see in the Solution Explorer that it isn't there.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should be able to remove the reference using the nuget command-line or GUI: uninstall-package Essential.Diagnostics

Comment: @WillBickford: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just noticed a file called "packages.config" in my project. I opened that, and it contained the suspect package. I deleted the file and re-installed the package. Successfully added now.

I guess that leaves the question, how are you supposed to properly remove a package then?

Comment: This also helps if uninstall-package is failing for some reason. I had a project stuck in an installed state so I removed my packages folder and cleared the config file to resolve it.